# Adding new attribute to JSON object in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have the API method below in NodeJS that calls a function, receives a JSON object `intent`, tries to add a new attribute "tested" and returns the object. The problem is that the new attribute "tested" is never displayed in the returned object. However, the value of the existing one "processed" is correctly changed. Any ideas?

```
function process_first(req, res, next) {
  Intent.getFirstUnprocessed()
    .then(intent => {
        intent.tested = "DONE";
        intent.processed = true;
        res.json(intent);
      })
    .catch(e => next(e));
}
```

`intent` has initially this value:

```
{"processed":false,"payload":"hello","createdAt":"2017-02-16T05:07:19.596Z"}
```

and it returns:

```
{"processed":true,"payload":"hello","createdAt":"2017-02-16T05:07:19.596Z"}
```

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: What **exactly** is `intent`. Does it happen to have a `toJSON` method?

Comment: try this intent["tested"] = "DONE" instead of intent.tested = "DONE"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intent object can be some custom object(returned by some library like mongoose). Most of the times you cannot modify these objects directly. You've to change them to plain javascript objects. These libraries provide you methods for this purpose (like toObject or toJSON). Additionally if it is a collection such as map or anything like that, it too has toObject method.

If object is a map Try this:

```
function process_first(req, res, next) {
  Intent.getFirstUnprocessed()
    .then(intent => {
        var intenObject = intent.toObject();
        intenObject.tested = "DONE";
        intenObject.processed = true;
        res.json(intenObject);
      })
    .catch(e => next(e));
}
```

If it is a json string

```
function process_first(req, res, next) {
  Intent.getFirstUnprocessed()
    .then(intent => {
        var intenObject = JSON.parse(intent);
        intenObject.tested = "DONE";
        intenObject.processed = true;
        res.json(intenObject);
      })
    .catch(e => next(e));
}
```